# WP_PLUGIN_URL equivalent

Tags: plugins, permalinks, https, http, plugins-url

I am using a plugin that uses WP_PLUGIN_URL and that cause mixed content issues.

This is the line of code:  `<img src="<?php echo esc_url( WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/plugin-name/images/icon1.png' ); ?>">`

I can't seem to find an equivalent to produce the same URL.

**This is what I tried:**
`<img src="<?php echo esc_url( plugins_url( '/plugin-name/images/icon1.png', dirname(__DIR__))); ?>">`

**plugins_url()** produces: `"/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/front/custom-woo-gallery/plugin-name/images/icon1.png"`

**content_url()** produces: `"/wp-content/plugin-name/images/icon1.png"`

If this is the wrong approach, how can I resolve the mixed content issue because of WP_PLUGINS_URL

Thanks

Comment: Are your [site URLs](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-your-wordpress-site-urls-step-by-step/) defined with `https`? Does the URL in browser also use `https`?

Comment: Hi @Caleb URLs in browsers are using https. I use a load balancer to handle the https on frontend. site url and address are not defined in https.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is expecting `http`, but you're visiting with `https` which is causing the mixed content error. Setting your site and address URLs to use `https` should solve your problem.

If you can't use `https` in the admin, then you'll need to try ways to tell WordPress to use `https` only on the frontend. Try something like this (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'site_url', static function ( $url ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $url;
    }

    return str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $url );
} );
```

Comment: I won't be able to use SSL on the server level. I'm using load balancer to handle front end https.

Comment: SSL at the server level is recommended, but I've updated my answer with a possible solution for changing URLs on frontend only.

Comment: @Caleb when you are behind load balancer the communication between the balancer and the server is many times over HTTP as there is no point in encription.

Comment: @PlainH2O sounds like the opposite solution will be easier, set the site to HTTPS, and convert at the server level at HTTP to HTTPS. This way you will not need to worry about the next plugin that will not be compatible with you non conventional setup

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks but I beg to differ. That's not non conventional setup. It is a cloud based solution. The SSL is attached to the load balancer and not on the server. I don't think I will get a wildcard SSL just to accommodate that plugin to use at the server level or to disable the load balancer. imho, the non conventional is WP_PLUGIN_URL that does not support https by default.

Comment: @PlainH2O please read again carefully what I suggested. As for non conventional... wordpress generates URL for the browser, you set it as HTTP to generate URLs that will be easier for the server. whether it is non conventional or not might be a matter of opinion, but not many plugin developers will expect that your site url is wrong on purpose